# Query two tables and display combined results without duplicates

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 for the VB.net front-end and an Access 2010 database for the back-end with an ODBC System DSN as the connection link.

I have the following two tables with their respective fields:

**tblRepairRequest** ([ID], [RequestType], [SubmitterFirstName], [SubmitterLastName],  [SubmitterIDNumber], [DateSubmitted], [TimeSubmitted], [SupervisorFirstName], [SupervisorLastName], [SupervisorIDNumber], [PositionLocation], [ProblemDescription], [DateClosed], [TimeClosed], [Status]) **Where** [ID] is the primary key (Auto generated number by the database)

**tblRepairRequstNotes** ([ID], [RepairRequestID], [NoteType], [UserFirstName], [UserLastName], [UserIDNumber], [DateNoted], [TimeNoted], [Notes]) **Where** [ID] is the primary key (Auto generated number by the database) and [RepairRequestID] is the foreign key (the primary key from tblRepairRequest)

There is a 1(tblRepairRequest) to Many(tblRepairRequestNotes) relationship between the two tables.

I have created a form with all the fields in these two tables laid out on the form.  This will be used to search the database.  The more fields on the form the user enters data into, the more refined the search will get (using AND with LIKE in the SQL statement).

I do not not want to show duplicates to the user.  So let's say the query runs and you get the following based on the search criteria:

-6 records from tblRepairRequest matched ([ID] 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, & 6)

-10 records from tblRepairRequestNotes matched ([RepairRequestID] 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 9, 9, 9, 15, 16)

These should be combined so that the results are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 15, 16.  Since the combined results are in essence my primary key [ID] from tblRepairRequest, I want the user to see the following fields from tblRepairRequest in a datagridview as the search results for each one of the [ID] numbers from those combined results:

[ID], [RequestType], [SubmitterFirstName], [SubmitterLastName], [SubmitterIDNumber], [DateSubmitted], [TimeSubmitted], [DateClosed], [TimeClosed], [Status]

This way I can have the user double-click a result and then I can show more details in a new form.

What I need help with is the SQL statement(s).  I just need to understand how the basic format of  the statement(s) needs to be. I am assuming there will be joins which for the life of me I am just not grasping.  Or maybe it needs to be done differently, like two separate queries and then somehow merge those results together, I really don't know.  I tried searching and nothing seemed right for what I am trying to do, either that or I am just totally lost (which very well could be).  Once I have the basic query structure down, I can get the rest. I will fill in the code to dynamically build the statement based on what data fields are filled in by the user.  I am not using a binding source.  I am doing it by code using data adapters, data sets, data views, and data tables and then I set the source property on my datagridview.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can build queries in access visually then move the SQL to your code; or it also has a Wizard to help build them until you have an inkling what you want or where to start.

Comment: Thank you so much @Plutonix for your comment.  I don't know why I did not think about using the query builder in Access to help me out.  I have been working on it today and think I have figured it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, I used Access query builder to assist me. I also found the following article to assist me: [Use a union query to combine multiple queries into a single result](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/use-a-union-query-to-combine-multiple-queries-into-a-single-result-HA102749627.aspx).

This is the resulting SELECT query:

"**SELECT** tblRepairRequests.ID, tblRepairRequests.RequestType, tblRepairRequests.SubmitterFirstName, tblRepairRequests.SubmitterLastName, tblRepairRequests.SubmitterIDNumber, tblRepairRequests.DateSubmitted, tblRepairRequests.TimeSubmitted, tblRepairRequests.DateClosed, tblRepairRequests.TimeClosed, tblRepairRequests.Status **FROM** tblRepairRequests **WHERE** " & strRepairRequestSearchCriteria & " **UNION SELECT** tblRepairRequests.ID, tblRepairRequests.RequestType, tblRepairRequests.SubmitterFirstName, tblRepairRequests.SubmitterLastName, tblRepairRequests.SubmitterIDNumber, tblRepairRequests.DateSubmitted, tblRepairRequests.TimeSubmitted, tblRepairRequests.DateClosed, tblRepairRequests.TimeClosed, tblRepairRequests.Status **FROM** tblRepairRequests **INNER JOIN** tblRepairRequestNotes **ON** tblRepairRequests.ID = tblRepairRequestNotes.RepairRequestID **WHERE** " & strNotesSearchCriteria &";"

Both strRepairRequestSearchCriteria and strNotesSearchCriteria are my compiled search criteria based on what search fields are filled in by the user.